# Crash in deleteNotificationChannel in Android 11

Tags: java, android, crash, foreground-service, android-11

In my app I use Foreground Service to show a notification when the app goes in background. I created a Notification Channel in the following way:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.app_name);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(TransactionsUtil.getNotificationChannelId(this), name, importance);
        channel.setDescription("some description");
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, TransactionsUtil.getNotificationChannelId(this))
            .setSmallIcon("some icon")
            .setContentTitle("some content")
            .setContentText("some content")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
      .setChannelId(TransactionsUtil.getNotificationChannelId(this))
            .build();
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

The I delete the notification channel in this way:

```
private void terminateService() {
    stopForeground(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(getNotificationChannelId(this));
    }
    stopSelf();
}
```

Recently, I'm having some crashes in my app releated to this; in particular, I have the following error:

*Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException
Not allowed to delete channel "channel name" with a foreground service*

The problem is releated to the function terminateService, in particular in deleteNotificationChannel.

*Caused by android.os.RemoteException
Remote stack trace: at com.android.server.notification.NotificationManagerService$11.enforceDeletingChannelHasNoFgService(NotificationManagerService.java:3859) at com.android.server.notification.NotificationManagerService$11.deleteNotificationChannel(NotificationManagerService.java:3872) at android.app.INotificationManager$Stub.onTransact(INotificationManager.java:1813) at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1170) at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1134)*

It happens only in Android 11 devices. Does someone has a solution or suggestion, please?

Comment: This is no way of asking question. go through this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok sorry, I tried to edit my question to make it more clear. I added the error lines I found in Crashlytics. I can't reproduce the crash with my Android 11 device, so I can't add more details in my question.

Comment: This is still not good. But, This exception simply telling that at some point the notification channel is was deleted and it wasn't allowed at that time. How can we know that what happened back then and this exception occured? We don't know which foreground service you are using and which data is being passed to background service.

Comment: I edited another time

Comment: Did you find the correct answer? I have faced this problem.

Comment: Not yet, nobody answered me.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to delete the channel, you can share the channel with your normal notification channel.
You get crash because `stopForeground` is binder call through `ActivityManagerService`, it cross process, same as the `deleteNotificationChannel` through `NotificationManagerService`, if the `NotificationManagerService` goes fast, the method `enforceDeletingChannelHasNoFgService` will return `true`, which is added from [android-11.0.0_r38](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-11.0.0_r38:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java), and you will get a crash.